# Can I apply a time dependant covariate to a cox regression with calendar-based time scale using data with staggered entry

Tags: regression, survival, censoring, dependent-variable

I have a retrospective study evaluating the effectiveness of an intervention in reducing COVID infections on subgroup of patients. Using a control and intervention group, I was hoping to set a time-based calendar scale to avoid having to account for the variation in local covid infection rates(as noted by this paper https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9933854/ ). However, this intervention was offered on a rolling basis in the first half of the year, and so I don’t have a uniform start date for each patient. Would I be able to apply a time dependent covariate only analyze the at risk population on that date at the time of the event.
I have a little under 1000 patients but here is a sample of the data. With time of entry and time of last visit along with date of covid infections.

Answer (score 0):

> Would I be able to apply a time dependent covariate only analyze the at risk population on that date at the time of the event.

That's what the counting-process data format for time-dependent covariates allows. With outcomes expressed as `Surv(startTime, stopTime, event)`, at each event time the software examines all the data rows and only picks out the rows representing cases that are at risk at that particular time. Technically, for each data row, the `startTime` is a left-truncation time, meaning that the data row provides *no* information about risks prior to that time. The `stopTime` is either an event time or a right-censoring time, depending on the `event` marker.

If your choice of a calendar-date time scale makes sense and your time-varying covariates are coded accordingly, then you can analyze such data with a Cox model.